# Babel compile Typescript exportDefaultFrom error

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I am using Babel to compile Typescript code and encounter this error:

```
{ SyntaxError: ....../node_modules/@apollographql/apollo-tools/lib/buildServiceDefinition.d.ts: Support for the experimental syntax 'exportDefaultFrom' isn't currently enabled (3:8):

  1 | import { GraphQLSchema, DocumentNode, GraphQLError } from "graphql";
  2 | import { GraphQLResolverMap } from "./schema/resolverMap";
> 3 | export interface GraphQLSchemaModule {
    |        ^
  4 |     typeDefs: DocumentNode;
  5 |     resolvers?: GraphQLResolverMap<any>;
  6 | }

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from (https://git.io/vb4yH) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

so I `npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from` and here is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/env",
      "@babel/typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"
  ]
}
```

however, the error persists. any suggestion?

thanks